# Shell Script - Unexpected token `then'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run a Shell Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_BROKER_ID" ]]; then
  export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
fi
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_LOG_DIRS" ]]; then
  export KAFKA_LOG_DIRS="/kafka/kafka-logs-$KAFKA_BROKER_ID"
fi
if [[ -n "$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" ]]; then
  sed -r -i "s/(export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS)=\"(.*)\"/\1=\"$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS\"/g" $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh
  unset KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
fi

for VAR in `env`
do
  if [[ $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_ && ! $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_HOME ]]; then
    kafka_name=`echo "$VAR" | sed -r "s/KAFKA_(.*)=.*/\1/g" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr _ .`
    env_var=`echo "$VAR" | sed -r "s/(.*)=.*/\1/g"`
    if egrep -q "(^|^#)$kafka_name=" $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties; then
      sed -r -i "s@(^|^#)($kafka_name)=(.*)@\2=${!env_var}@g" $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
    else
      echo "$kafka_name=${!env_var}" >> $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
    fi
  fi
done

#$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
```

I have tried the following :

> - Tried Changing #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh
> - Tried executing the file with    ./file.sh , sh file.sh and bash file.sh
> - Tried indentation of the code

But keep getting the same error :

```
start-kafka.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
start-kafka.sh: line 15: `  if [[ $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_ && ! $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_HOME ]]; then'
```

And have seen similar questions, but can't find a solution to this.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  That said, when I replace the commands with innocuous ones (e.g. by prefixing with `echo`) I get no syntax error from the code in the question.  Perhaps there's something peculiar to the values in your environment?

Comment: Are you running this on linux bash?

Comment: @avihoo - the tags would suggest so.

Comment: Might it be an issue with `[[`? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168259
I ran line 15 fine on my computer so it does seem that there is something wrong with the code per say, just that it's running in the wrong environment?

Comment: Possibly related, you cannot reliable iterate over your environment variables using a `for` loop like this.

Comment: Quite a few issues with your code. An MCVE, as Toby suggested, would help isolate this particular error, but a run through shellcheck.net wouldn't hurt. Two things stand out for me; first, you probably don't want to `for var in \`env\`` because of word splitting (try setting `FOO=$'BAR\nBAZ'` and see what `env` says); second, you could streamline all the assignment piplines in the `for` loop using bash alone -- no need for `sed` and `tr` here.  `kafka_name="${VAR,,}"; kafka_name="${kafka_name%%=*}"; kafka_name="${kafka_name#*_}"`

Comment: @ArunVeeramani : Run it with `bash -x file.sh` and examine the output, which then hopefully will point out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked at last. There were no errors on the code. As [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight)
 said, I rewrote the entire code line-by-line by prefixing echo to find any syntax errors.

But, when checking the 20th line where **else** is present, I got some error. But, It eventually got solved.

Looked as though it was an issue with **else** belonging to which **if** statement (line 18 or line 15). I assume for such indentation issues using IDE would be a good choice.

Answer (score -2):

in this line:

```
if egrep -q "(^|^#)$kafka_name=" $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties; then
```

are missing brackets `[]`
Maybe this can solve your problem.

Comment: `if` doesn't need brackets, it executes a command and evaluates it's return code. Brackets are just a short form of writing a test, `[` is usually a shell builtin or a symlink `/usr/bin/[ -> /usr/bin/test`